# Two scenes at the same time in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to have a game scene, and on the bottom a permanent game menu for things like inventory, etc. I thought it would be great to have two scenes: one for the actual game and another for the game menu. How can I do this in SpriteKit? Having two scenes at the same time (and each one having its own nodes and such)

Also, if this is not the best way to implement this, please tell me.

Comment: 2 scenes seems like a waste of resources and is not recommended.  Why not just have 2 nodes on 1 scene,  1 for your menu, 1 for your actual game,  and set the menu node to the max z position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No don't do that. Even if possible it is meaningless.

In a such case I use storyboard. Created menu at top of the screen and give the rest of the screen to `SKView`. By this way you can control your `SKScene` easily also you can use UIKit for you menu which is more advanced than SpriteKit ui elements.

Also you can use one scene and create menu nodes with SpriteKit utilities.